# How to insert a paragraph before TOC (Table of contents)

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx, tableofcontents

I am trying to insert a paragraph before TOC using python-docx.
Is there a way in which I can add the paragraph before the TOC.

This is what currently I have

> [image: This is what currently I have]

I want something like this

> [image]

Comment: You need to show your code so that people can try it and find how to make it work. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```
paragraph = document.paragraphs[0].insert_paragraph_before(
    "New paragraph here"
)
```

Comment: yes I have tried this. The TOC is the very first thing on the first page. So the text (New paragraph here) gets added after the TOC.

Comment: You should add those details to your question. It shows you've tried some things and gives a respondent more to go on to help you.